# NOT IN with Subquery SQL Construct

Tags: sql, oracle

```
ACTOR (id, fname, lname, gender)
MOVIE (id, name, year, rank)
CASTS (pid, mid, role)
WHERE pid references ACTOR id
mid references Movie id
```

List the movies that x has been in without y (x and y are actors).

I am finding it difficult to construct an SQL with NOT in. This is my attempt. Im unable to fininsh it off due to the second actor not being present

```
SELECT m.name
FROM MOVIE m
WHERE m.id NOT IN (SELECT c.mid
                       FROM CASTS c, ACTOR a
                       WHERE c.pid = a.id AND a.name = "adam..")
```

Comment: No, your query is not correct.  For instance, it only mentions one actor, but your question mentions two actors.

Comment: is there another subquery to take into account the Non existence of the second actor? how would you do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using **`NOT EXISTS`**:

```
SELECT m.name                       -- Show the names                      
FROM movie m                        -- of all movies
WHERE EXISTS                        -- that there was
      ( SELECT *                    -- a role
        FROM casts c                -- casted to
          JOIN actor a              -- actor with
            ON c.pid = a.id
        WHERE c.mid = m.id  
          AND a.name = 'Actor X'    -- name X
      ) 
  AND NOT EXISTS                    -- and there was not
      ( SELECT *                    -- any role
        FROM casts c                -- casted
          JOIN actor a              -- to actor with
            ON c.pid = a.id
        WHERE c.mid = m.id 
          AND a.name = 'Actor Y'    -- name Y
      ) ;
```

You can also use **`NOT IN`**. Note that this may give you unexpected results if there are rows with `NULL` in the `movie.id` or `casts.mid` column:

```
SELECT m.name                       -- Show the names                      
FROM movie m                        -- of all movies
WHERE m.id IN                       -- but keep only the movies that
      ( SELECT c.mid                -- movies that
        FROM casts c                -- had a role casted to
          JOIN actor a              -- actor with
            ON c.pid = a.id
        WHERE a.name = 'Actor X'    -- name X
      ) 
  AND m.id NOT IN                   -- and not the movies
      ( SELECT c.mid                -- that
        FROM casts c                -- had a role casted
          JOIN actor a              -- to actor with
            ON c.pid = a.id
        WHERE a.name = 'Actor Y'    -- name Y
      ) ;
```

Comment: Two correlated subqueries instead of one? My Oracle is a little rusty, but in SQL Server, this would be more overhead than doing a traditional join for Actor X.

Comment: @imthepitts The problem with a join in this case is that we need a semi-join, not a join. If there are actors with more than one role in the same movie, a join will give duplicate results. All other join answers seem to have missed this point.

Comment: @ypercube That's true, but it's easy enough to add a `DISTINCT` to the `SELECT` clause and call it a day.

Comment: @imthepitts Would a `JOIN + DISTINCT` be more efficient than a correlated `EXISTS` subquery?

Comment: @ypercube, I'm not sure with Oracle, but my understanding of any correlated subquery is that it is inefficient because it executes the inner queries for each row in the outer query. I've seen this completely murder an application that was otherwise working well in SQL Server.

Comment: So it comes out to `(Outer Query) + (Inner Query 1 * Outer Query Rows) + (Inner Query 2 * Outer Query Rows)`.

Comment: @imthepitts Correlated subqueries can be expensive, but in SQL you normally want the most efficient method to solve the current problem.  sometimes there's no "efficient" way to do it, and you need to pick the least inefficient.  A correlated subquery here is likely more efficient than `JOIN + DISTINCT` because of the very large overhead in calculating the larger resultset then filtering it out

Comment: @JNK, I agree in principle, but for this result set, it will be a small number of records. Actors are only in a few hundred movies in their career (at most), and they are RARELY playing more than one character in those movies. So the joined data set will only ever be slightly larger than the final filtered set.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the often-overlooked `MINUS`:

```
SELECT Movie.id, Movie.name
  FROM Actor
  INNER JOIN Casts ON Actor.id = Casts.pid
  INNER JOIN Movie ON Casts.mid = Movie.id
  WHERE Actor.id = 1
MINUS SELECT Movie.id, Movie.name
  FROM Actor
  INNER JOIN Casts ON Actor.id = Casts.pid
  INNER JOIN Movie ON Casts.mid = Movie.id
  WHERE Actor.id = 2
```

The `WHERE Actor.id` in the queries above can be substituted with some other way to uniquely identify the actor, for example by their name.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    Movie a
        INNER JOIN Casts b
            ON a.ID = b.mID
        INNER JOIN Actor c
            ON b.pid = c.ID
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  aa.mid
            FROM    Casts aa
                    INNER JOIN Actor bb
                        ON aa.pid = bb.ID
            WHERE   bb.fName = 'Y_Name'
        ) d ON  a.id = d.mid
WHERE   c.fname = 'X_Name' AND
        d.mid IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31f3c/3)

The reason for having extra join on the subquery is because we are filtering the records by the name of the actor.

---

Assuming you have these set of records

ACTOR

```
╔════╦════════╗
║ ID ║ FNAME  ║
╠════╬════════╣
║  1 ║ X_Name ║
║  2 ║ Y_Name ║
╚════╩════════╝
```

MOVIE

```
╔════╦══════╗
║ ID ║ NAME ║
╠════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ Mov1 ║
║  2 ║ Mov2 ║
║  3 ║ Mov3 ║
╚════╩══════╝
```

CAST

```
╔═════╦═════╗
║ PID ║ MID ║
╠═════╬═════╣
║   1 ║   1 ║ <<== EXPECTED OUTPUT since Y_NAME is not present
║   1 ║   2 ║                      on Movie Mov1
║   2 ║   2 ║
║   1 ║   3 ║
║   2 ║   3 ║
╚═════╩═════╝
```

**THE OUTPUT**

```
╔════╦══════╗
║ ID ║ NAME ║
╠════╬══════╣
║  1 ║ Mov1 ║
╚════╩══════╝
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation and demonstration using the SQL fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

First get all the movies for Actor X. Then check filter out any movies that also contain Actor Y.

```
SELECT m.name
FROM MOVIE m, CASTS c, ACTOR a
WHERE m.id = c.mid
    AND c.pid = a.id
    AND a.name = "ACTOR X"
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM CASTS c1, ACTOR a1
        WHERE c1.pid = a1.id
            AND m.id = c1.mid
            AND a1.name = "ACTOR Y"
    )
```

Comment: whats 1 after the SELECT in the subquery?

Comment: `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` are boolean comparisons. For each row in the outer query, it returns `true` if a row is found, `false` if a row is not found. In that way it filters the outer query with the results of the inner query. Since all we care about is a true/false, we want to select something that is trivial for the database. You could just as easily `SELECT *`, but it increases overhead.

Comment: Why are you avoiding the `JOIN` keyword?

Comment: Just keeping my syntax consistent with @Hoody's.

Comment: You can select anything in an `EXISTS`, it won't be evaluated.  I normally use `select 1/0`, just for fun.

Comment: To tack on to what @jonearles said, all RDBMS I am aware of ignore the `SELECT` list in an `EXISTS` subquery.  Using `1` is still a good practice to show that you don't care about what's returned, but there would be no overhead by using `*` or some other column name.